# replacing new line characters with comma from given text

Tags: php

Here I have tried to replace newline char with comma. I checked previous threads and acted accordingly but still no solution.

```
$letters = '#\s+#';
$rep   = ',';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $rep, trim($text));
echo $output;
```

Link to demo : http://ideone.com/DoFOSc

Comment: 1. You are trying to make a regular expression replace using `str_replace`. `preg_replace` is for that.
2. To replace the newline with a comma you have to `str_replace("\n", ",", trim($text));`

Comment: I'm not a regex expert, but I'm quite sure this doesn't target new line character...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) is for string replace and not for regex replace. [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) should be used if you want to do a regex-based replace. However, you could replace each new line with a comma using:

```
$output = str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n"), ",", $text);
```

Comment: No, I would ADD a "\r\n", not change "\n" for it. Put them both

Comment: Haha, you are true again my friend. I was in such hurry i just did and didn't think. I'm better than that :)

Comment: Fixed it for you, @ZtripezHellström. Feel free to roll back if you think the edit changed the answer too much :)

Comment: \r\n should be first in the array and a space after the comma if you need readability.

`$output = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), ", ", $text);`

Answer (score 3):

using regex

```
preg_replace('|\n|', ',', $text)
```

Comment: Why would you use a regex for such a simple task?